# Sending eth and erc20 token to contract and airdrop them out fails

Tags: contract-development

I wrote a smart contract where It should allow to fund contract with some ethereum and erc20 token that I made. Problem is that when I send eth transaction fails. Same as if I try to send my erc20 token.

My token:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x8966504a3b07e2cecd4f4bbb3d51566c7127b156

Transactions failed:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x00c7aab231a8e6c2b02ad6db5f3e9cbf7f380e287347402f4e358866ffa40b2c

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xab168ba0357ad55ae7d4f79eac669951e7720cdf6ab29621ead39a58bd35623e

Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./ERC20Interface.sol";
//import "./ownership/Ownable.sol";
//import "./ownership/Whitelist.sol";
import "./Ownable.sol";
import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract AirdropContract is Ownable{

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    ERC20Interface token;
    uint256 private amountOfEther;
    uint256 private amountOfFun;

    event DropedEth(address from, address to, uint256 amount);
    event DropedFun(address from, address to, uint256 amount);

    event SentEthToContract(address from, address to, uint256 amount);
    event SentFunToContract(address from, address to, uint256 amount);

    constructor(ERC20Interface _token) public {
        token = _token;
    }

    // assign admin (access to fund contract and airdrop)
    function assignAdmin(address admin_address) public onlyOwner {
        assignAdmin(admin_address);
    }

    // fund contract with eth callback function
    function () public payable ownerAndAdmin{
        amountOfEther = amountOfEther.add(msg.value);
        emit SentEthToContract(msg.sender, address(this), msg.value);
    }

    function sendFunToContract(uint256 amount) public ownerAndAdmin returns(bool success){
        token.transfer(address(this), amount);
        amountOfFun = amountOfFun.add(amount);

        emit SentFunToContract(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        return true;
    }

    function dropEth(address[] recipients, uint256[] values) public payable ownerAndAdmin  returns(bool success)
    {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
            recipients[i].transfer(values[i]);

            emit DropedEth(address(this), recipients[i], values[i]);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function dropFun(address[] recipients, uint256[] values) public {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
            token.transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);

            emit DropedFun(address(this), recipients[i], values[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I used this migration to deploy:

```
const AirdropContract = artifacts.require("./AirdropContract")

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(AirdropContract, 0x8966504a3B07E2cECD4f4bBb3d51566c7127B156);
};
```

Also my ownable:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions".
 */
contract Ownable {
    address public owner;
    mapping(address => bool) private admins;

    /**
     * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
     * account.
     */
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }


    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    modifier ownerAndAdmin() {
        require(msg.sender == owner || admins[msg.sender]);
        _;
    }


    /**
     * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
     * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
     */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        if (newOwner != address(0)) {
            owner = newOwner;
      }
    }

    // assign admin (access to fund contract and airdrop)
    function assignAdmin(address admin_address) public onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "wrong address");
        require(!admins[admin_address], "already added");
        admins[admin_address] = true;
    }

    // remove admin (access to fund contract and airdrop)
    function removeAdmin(address admin_address) public onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "wrong address");
        require(admins[admin_address], "not admin yet");
        admins[admin_address] = false;
    }
}
```

How do I invoke sending the eth and erc20 correctly then? I am trying via MEW.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to transfer tokens from your address to the airdrop contract address

In javascript you can do somethink like this

```
tokenContract.methods.transfer(airdropContract.address, amountTokens)
    .send({ from: accountWithTokens })
```

You can also use a wallet like MEW to transfer token to the airdrop contract address. You do not have to call your aidrop contract but the token contract.

Actually you function `sendFunToContract` is wrong

```
function sendFunToContract(uint256 amount) public ownerAndAdmin returns(bool success){
    token.transfer(address(this), amount);
    amountOfFun = amountOfFun.add(amount);

    emit SentFunToContract(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    return true;
}
```

It is sending tokens to itself with `token.transfer(address(this), amount)`. Which will fail if the contract doesn't have enough balance.